# Countable sets bijective function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have the infinite set $\{\ldots, - 1,-2,0,1,2,\ldots\}$

If the set is countable then there will be a bijective function which maps elements of this set to the set containing all natural numbers.

However, I can't find any such function. Does this prove the set is uncountable?

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I have tried to find the bijenction function but failed for example I can easily prove than the set {2,4,6,8...}is countable because the bijenction function f(n) = 2n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the set is uncountable,

you would have to prove there is no bijective function from it to $\mathbb N$.

In fact, here is one:

$f(j)=\begin{cases}-2j\;\text{ if } j\le0\\\\2j-1\;\text{ if } j>0.\end{cases}.$

Comment: There are different conventions about whether $\mathbb N$ contains $0$; here I assumed it does; if not, just add $1$

Comment: Okay it is too hard.

Comment: Wait why-2j?Shouldnt it be - j?

Comment: It may have been easier for you to find a bijective function from $\mathbb N$ taking  $0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...$

Comment: $f(j)=\begin{cases}-j\;\text{ if } j\le0\\\\2j-1\;\text{ if } j>0.\end{cases}$ wouldn't be bijective, because we'd have $f(-7)=f(4)$, for example

Comment: OK ty a lot for your time.

Comment: That wouldn't be bijective, because we'd have $f(-7)=f(7)$, for example

Comment: Yes I understood it.

Comment: you are welcome